# Unable to authenticate using after implementing Bcrypt PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bcrypt

after implementing Bcrypt Password Encoder, I'm unable to authenticate (invalid credentials). Here is the user I'm adding:

```
userRepository.save(new User("First", "Last", "user", "user" , "email@email.com", "12345", superRoles));
```

When I view the JSON for the page, I see that the password is hashed. However, when I try to enter the password "user", I am unable to authenticate:

```
..."password": "$2a$10$ZwUxEGVDAgI4qgkas0bEO.BmU1WrMXk1zQA5Jc70m.e6reiL3M7BG"...
```

Can anyone spot if I'm doing anything wrong? Code is posted below. Thank you in advance!

**User class:**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    private long userId;
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String userPhone;
    private String userEmail;
    //others, such as List for roles, etc.

    public User() { }

    public User(String userFirstName, String userLastName, String username, String password, String userPhone, String userEmail, Map<String, Boolean> userRoles) {
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
        this.username = username;
        setPassword(password);
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
    }
        // other getters and setters
}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/login"
                    ).permitAll()
...
// taken out for brevity
    }
}
```

**DetailsService:**

```
@Component
public class DetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository users;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = users.findByUsername(username);
        // Roles are implemented in the entity in a Map<String, Boolean>, e.g. "ROLE_ADMIN" : true, to help with easily setting new permissions on the front end
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : user.getUserRoles().entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(true)) {
                roles.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        String[] permissions = roles.toArray(new String[roles.size()]);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " was not found");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(permissions)
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/login",
                        "/home",
                        "/visitor-area",
                        "/site.css",
                        "/app.js",
                        "/create-account",
                        "/css/*",
                        "/saveUser",
                        "/users"
                ).permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user-dashboard")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code (simplified it a bit by removing the roles and such) and your code works fine for me without the `MD5PasswordEncoder`. Make sure that the `repository.save()` method is actually called and that your security configuration (the part you've taken out) works correctly.

Comment: Indeed, everything else _should_ be perfect - see edit 2. Everything works fine without bcrypt, but as soon as I implement it it stops authenticating. Would it make any difference if I'm loading in my users via a class that implements `ApplicationRunner`? As I said, it works fine without bcrypt.. Been at it for days :)

Comment: Well, your original code (with BCrypt) works for me as well. However, I don't understand why you have both a form login and basic authentication. Which of these two do you use? And why do you have `authorizeRequests()` multiple times?

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning as I'm going and working with different snippets from different sources. With all of that removed and just using `formLogin()`, it still doesn't work so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why it works for you but not me. Have updated the question to reflect the new `configure` method.

Comment: Also @g00glen00b, when you mentioned that I should make sure the `repository.save()` method is actually called - that's done in my `DatabaseLoader` class that implements `ApplicationRunner`. Does it need to be done anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

When I encrypted the password on the `User` entity, it would not authenticate. To fix it, I reverted back to a regular `String password`, getter/setter and `setPassword(password)` in the constructor. Then, in the class that implements `ApplicationRunner`, I encoded the password there:

```
    String password = "user";
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

    userRepository.save(new User("First", "Last", "user", hashedPassword , "email@email.com", "12345", superRoles));
```